# Packer: create docker image with ubuntu and nginx

Tags: packer

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y nginx

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/usr/sbin/nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Building the container and running it through the following commands works:

```
$ docker build -t web:1.0 .
$ docker run -itd -p 8200:80 --name webserver1 web:1.0
```

I made an equivalent Packer file as follows:

```
packer {
  required_plugins {
    docker = {
      version = ">= 1.0.1"
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/docker"
    }
  }
}

source "docker" "ubuntu" {
  image  = "ubuntu:bionic"
  commit = true
  changes = [
    "EXPOSE 80",
    "CMD [\"/usr/sbin/nginx\", \"-g\", \"daemon off;\"]"
  ]
}

build {
  name = "learn-packer"
  sources = [
    "source.docker.ubuntu"
  ]

  provisioner "shell" {
    inline = [
      "apt-get -y update",
      "apt-get install -y nginx",
    ]
  }

  post-processors {
    post-processor "docker-tag" {
      repository = var.docker_repo
      tags       = ["1.1"]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm creating the image with `packer build .` When I run the image through Docker

```
docker run -itd -p 8201:80 --name webserver2 xxx/web:1.1
```

I get the following error:

```
usr/sbin/nginx: 1: usr/sbin/nginx: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

Comment: Possibly it should be /usr/sbin/nginx

Comment: Good catch thanks but that was a copy/paste error unfortunately. Issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add ENTRYPOINT [""] to make this work. Like so:

```
changes = [
  "EXPOSE 80",
  "CMD [\"/usr/sbin/nginx\", \"-g\", \"daemon off;\"]",
  "ENTRYPOINT [\"\"]",
]
```